# google maps failure to zoom into current location

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to zoom into my current location on android app. The map still defaults to africa. Doesn't zoom into my current location .

Edit code , afther refering to answer. Still no luck with getting GPS values.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();
           googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
           LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


           Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); 
           String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


           // Getting Current Location
           Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

           if(location == null){
               LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    double lat= location.getLatitude();
                    double lng = location.getLongitude();
                    LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 20));                    
                }
                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                        Bundle extras) {}
                };
             Log.d("APpln", "well hello there >>"+location);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, locationListener);

           }else{
               double lat= location.getLatitude();
               double lng = location.getLongitude();

               LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);

               googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 20));
           }


        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
           LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
               public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                 // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                 makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
               }

               private void makeUseOfNewLocation(Location location) {
                   double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
                LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + lat + "\nLong: " + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

               public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

               public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
             };

             locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);      


            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

Manifext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pcakage"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<permission
        android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
 <uses-permission 
     android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 
    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"/>
    <uses-feature android:required="true"/>

    <!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="package.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
     <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="some_value" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. WHen I print values on lat and long , i get no values . Which possibly means the `Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)`  isn't getting the location. Ihas it got to do with access?

Comment: did you added the permission for get the user location? i.e. <!-- Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: I did actually. I have added my manifext.xml

Comment: @misguided Are you getting location ? Will you please log it . It seems like getLastKnownLocation is null

Comment: You are right location is `null`. But I don't know why .

Comment: @misguided many time it happens when your device doesn't have Last Location solution is to use requestLocationUpdate and implementLocationListener which provide method onLocationChanged which will provide updated location.so here you can animate/zoom location

Comment: Have you added the relevant permissions in your manifest file ? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`

Comment: @GrIsHu yes have done the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometime can happen that you can't get a valid location from `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);`

Start a location listener and move the camera when you get a location.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();
       googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
       LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

       Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

       String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

       Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

       if(location == null){

         LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            double lat= location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 20));
         }

         LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, locationListener);


       }else{
          double lat= location.getLatitude();
          double lng = location.getLongitude();

          LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);

          googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 20));
      }

    }
    }
```

Comment: locationListener  doesn't work , if all implemented methods are not used.I have implemented the same. But I get a error when i place `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, locationListener)` . Can you please advise.

Comment: I just noticed there is a typo, it's      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, locationListener)

Comment: Mate have updated the code, but still don't see the device zooming in to current gps location

Comment: you are requesting location update for the second locationListener you created...can you see your toast message?

Comment: Nope I can't see my toast message.

Comment: that's weird you sure you have location enabled on your device?

Comment: Mate thanks for that . WOrks prefectly now. I had the GPS satellite enabled , but the Google's location service wasn't. ALso implementing the two actioned listeners was another user error by me. Removed the redundant code and it all works fine now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead to use the standard best provider try get available better provider by hands (sea [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html))

```
Location getCurrentLocation()
{
    // Defining current location by the best providers, that availble at runtime on current device;
    Location location = null;
    @Nonnull String[] providers = new String[3];
    providers[0] = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    providers[1] = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    providers[2] = LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER;

    for (@Nonnull String provider : providers)
    {
        if (!mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) continue;
     //            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_UPDATES, this);
        if (mLocationManager != null)
        {
            location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (location != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return location;
}
```

and focused on map

```
private void focusMapOnCurrentLocation()
{
    final int DURATIONMS_CONST = 2000;
    final int ZOOM_ANIM_CAMERA_CONST = 15;
    final int ZOOM_MOVE_CAMERA_CONST = 20;

    // Set focus on current location on google map;

    Location location = getCurrentLocation();
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double log = location.getLongitude();
    @Nonnull LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, log);
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, ZOOM_MOVE_CAMERA_CONST));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(ZOOM_ANIM_CAMERA_CONST), DURATIONMS_CONST, null);
}
```

The same  you can use mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);